# Windows 10 Search: Add custom keywords to shortcuts to make them appear in search

Tags: windows-10, search, keyword

How do I add keywords to a shortcut, for example, add `Timestamp` and `Watermark` keywords to `Jambula` shortcut, so I can simply search **Timestamp** and have it appear in the search results (not the File explorer search) instead of when typing "Jambula" alone?

[image]

I already tried adding a comment containing the keywords, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Rename the shortcut to include the keywords?

Comment: That will definitely work, but it will be ugly, isn't there a workaround? Typing "Document" shows "Word" in the results, I want to do something similar.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @huang yes, switch to linux or mac 

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Cool.